# Excel Chart Title - how do I change font size when using cell reference?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a chart in Excel with the Title linked to a cell `=REPORT_PAGE!$A$1`
The formula in A1 looks like this:
`=ProductName & ": Project Performance" & CHAR(10) & 
"SPI: " & TEXT(VLOOKUP(TODAY(),ProjectData,13,TRUE),"0#.0#") & CHAR(10) & 
"EV: " & TEXT(VLOOKUP(TODAY(),ProjectData,11,TRUE),"#.0#%") & CHAR(10) & 
"PV: " & TEXT(VLOOKUP(TODAY(),ProjectData,12,TRUE),"#.0#%")`

This provides a Title which is all the same size; something like this:

> **BIG CHART TITLE
>
>   BIG METRIC 1
>
>   BIG METRIC 2
>
>   BIG METRIC 3**

I need something that can change the title to look more like this:

> **BIG CHART TITLE**
>   small-font metric 1
>   small-font metric 2
>   small-font metric 3

I suppose the other question is, "Can this be done without VB?"

Comment: Do i understand that right, you want only a *part* of the string that the formula produce in a different font/size, not the complete cell?

Comment: "Can this be done without VB?" - no there is no way for that, you need VBA for it

Comment: Aganju - that is correct.